# How do I stop a screen capture with FFmpeg under Windows in a bash script?

Tags: windows-10, bash, ffmpeg, python

When I capture the screen with `ffmpeg -i desktop` in a Bash script under Windows, I cannot end the capture with `taskkill /f`, because then FFmpeg won't write the MP4 header.

It has to be shutdown with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

How do I send <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to FFmpeg while it is running in background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop ffmpeg, you can send `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` with python's `os.kill`, but you have to send it to the **WINPID**, not the PID:

```bsh
WINPID=$(ps aux | grep ffmpeg | awk '{print $4}')
python -c "import os, signal; os.kill($WINPID, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)"
```

See a full example here:
https://gist.github.com/elsamuko/9c3fe69f00a0f847251ffa3ef1d080a2

References:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6336
https://bugs.python.org/issue42962

Comment: Excellent self-answered question!